# Why won't my SMS app write to a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql, collections, iteration

I'm building a SMS app in the form of a windows service, which listens for new messages on a COM port, then writes the messages to a SQL Server database. I'm using a third party library called `GSMComm` to achieve this.

The problem is when I iterate through the collection of messages obtained from the GSM modem, and then attempt to put them into the database, it throws an exception

> System.NotImplementedException:SmsDeliverPdu.ToString() not implemented.

Could anyone help?

```
private void SMSGetter()
{
    Log("Getter Fired");

    //var message = GSM.ReadMessage(4);
    //GSM.ReadMessage(4);
    //TcpClientChannel client = new TcpClientChannel();
    //ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(client, false);
    //string url = "192.168.100.67:2000";
    //ISmsSender smssender = (ISmsSender)Activator.GetObject(typeof(ISmsSender), url);

    try
    {
        DecodedShortMessage[] messages = Comm.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, PhoneStorageType.Sim);

        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=*******;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=*****;Password=*************");

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        com.Connection = Conn;

        Conn.Open();

        foreach (DecodedShortMessage message in messages)
        {
           com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO SMSArchives(Message,Blacklist) VALUES ('" +message.Data + "', 'Yes')");
           com.ExecuteNonQuery();
           //com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO SMSArchives(Message,Blacklist) VALUES (@par1,@par2)");
           //com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par1", message.ToString());
           //com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par2", "Yes");
           //com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        Conn.Close();
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is very clear, implement tostring to that class

Comment: SmsDeliverPdu is this a type?

Comment: seems like the last function is being called from somewhere in your code https://github.com/welly87/GSMComm/blob/master/PDUConverter/GsmComm.PduConverter/SmsDeliverPdu.cs

Comment: SmsDeliverPdu is a class in the third party Library, and I've refactored my code to message.data.Tostring() but it still comes up with the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.Data` returns a `SmsDeliverPdu` which has no `ToString()` implementation so concatenating `message.Data` to a string will fail.

You need to insert `message.Data.UserDataText` (or whatever is appropriate)

Comment: This seems to have worked, but now I'm getting an error from SQLcommand saying incorrect syntax near t?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing SmsDeliverPdu is a library you have downloaded from somewhere?  A quick search didn't turn anything up on it.  But the error message is usually the default error thrown when you automatically create methods in Visual Studio.  If you wrote the class that does this, you  didn't go back and write any code in the ToString method.  If you got the library from someone else, they didn't.

By the way, you should really look into paramterized queries.  You're code allows for SQL Injection.